# MySQL and Python, SEARCH DB

Tags: python, mysql

If guys can help me solve that problem i will be appreciate it.

```
def busca(valor):
    with conecta() as conexao:
        with conexao.cursor() as cursor:

            query = 'SELECT ativo_op FROM tradebook WHERE ativo_op LIKE ?'
            cursor.execute(query, (f'%{valor}%',))

            for i in cursor.fetchall():
                print(i)


busca('WIN')
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Python MySQL modules use `%s` as the placeholder, not `?` so it should be `LIKE %s`

Comment: Holy moly! Thanks, i'm here for hours trying figure out this! Thanks again!